# How to Fetch Records from Existing Mysql database and add number of rows to new database equal to records selected

Tags: php, mysql

I have current mysql database and i want to make a query to this database with php and if any number of rows are selected based on this mysql query. I want to take variables from these selected rows and want to add this data to new mysql database i.e select rows from old database selected with WHERE clause and add these rows to new database. Is it possible in mysql with php. Thanks in advance.

Comment: looks to me you need `INSERT INTO.... SELECT`

Comment: well, what do you want to here - yes it is.

Comment: if yes. then suggest me example code.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply :

```
INSERT INTO NewDB.YourTable
SELECT * FROM OldDB.YourTable
WHERE ...
```

Comment: can u please give me more details

Comment: About what? This is the full query needed

Comment: what to do if i want to copy some columns only? Not the entire row.

Comment: Then select only the columns you want to copy.. come on dude, this is basic SQL. `SELECT col1, col2, col5, ..`

Comment: am sorry sir, i am new to mysql and php

Comment: what if old table and new table column titles are different?

Comment: Please refer here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp , and try to learn something.

Comment: Thanks so much. You saved my day.